# android camera is not opening to capture image

Tags: java, android

**here is the camera intent**

```
 if(f[which].equals("Camera")) {
                    try {
                        String imageFileName="outputImage_" + System.currentTimeMillis()+".png";
                        File outputImageFile=new File(pictureSaveFolderPath,imageFileName);
                        if(outputImageFile.exists()){
                            outputImageFile.delete();
                        }
                        outputImageFile.createNewFile();
                        imageUri=getImageUriByOsVersion(outputImageFile);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,imageUri);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

**onActivity result**

```
 if (requestCode == 1) {
                Uri selectedImage=imageUri;
                getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage,null);
                ContentResolver cr=getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
                try {
                    thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                            cr, selectedImage);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                    common.setBitmap(thumbnail);

                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), thumbnail);
                File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));
            }
```

**Runtime Permission**

```
 private  boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
        int camera = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        int writePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int readPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (camera != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        }
        if (writePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }if (readPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {
                Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<>();
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                        perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
                    if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && perms.get(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && perms.get(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    } else {
                        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                            showDialogOK("Sorry, Camera and Storage Permission required for this activity. So please ensure the Camera and Storage permissions are enabled in settings",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            switch (which) {
                                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                                    checkAndRequestPermissions();
                                                    break;
                                            } }
                                    });
                        }
                    } }
            } }
    }
```

//AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.any"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
```

I am implementing camera,gallery and filemanger intent also this code is worked few days back i don't know what happend it is not working now.gallery and filemanager is working perfectly as i expected but the camera intent is not at all working.

Note:java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10363 does not have permission

I am getting the above error when i select camera option

Comment: post your `AndroidManifest.xml` file here

Comment: @RahulKhurana please check the above edited code

Comment: You are missing Camera permission in the file

Comment: i tried with camera permission its not working

Comment: you must declare all the permissions in the manifest file if you want to use it. There is no other way

Comment: i had declared in manifest  also i checked the intent.the camera  is not at all opening

Comment: check in the app settings if all the permissions are given. If not then recheck your code for asking runtime permissions

Comment: i checked in app permission camera and storage permissions are given

Comment: update your AndroidManifest file

Comment: please check the updated code

Comment: still getting the same error?

Comment: yes still camera is not working

Comment: Change your onActivityResult and use `FileProvider` to get the file

Answer (score 0):

You can use basicly request permission on runtime, also i didnt get permission like your style but i can get permission on runtime like this code :

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.[YourPermission]},
                        1);


@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {

            case 1:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // do something
                } else {
                    // do something
                }
                break;
}
```

Comment: sorry i tried your code it is not working the error remains same

Comment: I think you should check your permission condition. "perms.get(..)" returns object but  "PackageManager.permission.'permission'" returns integer value. Did you check that stuation?

Comment: Would you like to check it please? I am waiting for your answer because i am wondering how will it solve. Hope you solve it quickly. Good luck.

Comment: You can use above code to check permission granted or denied. You can reproduce the permissions request and cases. So maybe you can create new dummy project and test it. After than you can put that worked code on your main project.

Answer (score 0):

To open a camera you need this permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"> </uses-permission>
```

For run time permission you can use this library
        https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter

and after that

just call this function

```
 Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 100);
```

your picture wil saved in the default directory. To get picture path you need to call

```
  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01); //sets imageview as the bitmap
        imageview.setImageBitmap(image);
    }
}
```

Comment: the way you suggested for camera intent Is working but the captured picture is not clear

Comment: when you capture image you can get image path from the onActivityResult

Comment: that i know, my issue is captured image is not clear

Comment: when you capture a image you need image path right?? 

          Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

You can use this bitmap

Comment: i used this bitmap its working fine did you notice my point that the captured image is not clear its like blurry image

Comment: which device you are using?? and if it works for you please accept my answer

Comment: i am using redmi

Comment: then it is your device problem. can you test it from your default camera apps.